# How to download Microsoft Office 2016 or some equivalent?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, ms-office

I am a rookie with Mac.
I need to open Excel, Word, and maybe I forgot about something else, but these two I really need.

After I look through the internet as far as I understood, the most useful for this case is Microsoft Office. I found some video tutorials on how to download it for free, but the links that were provided by that tutorials now are disabled.

Could you please give me advice should I buy Microsoft Office or maybe there are some other app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the free office clone LibreOffice

http://www.libreoffice.org